# Elasticsearch monitoring settings

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

In the monitoring tab of Kibana it is mentioned that `Monitoring is currently off`

[image]

We need to enable `xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled` setting somewhere.
Where do we need to edit this setting?

I know we can click on this button and enable it automatically but I want to know in which file does it enable this setting.

I have checked `kibana.yml`, `elasticsearch.yml` and `advanced settings in kibana` and i could not find anything related to this.

Comment: The "Turn on monitoring" should be a button that enables monitoring or leads you to some documentation on how to enable it. just click it.

Comment: @EisenRatte it enables it, but it should be enabling this in some config file, i want to know that file's location

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Link to the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/monitoring-settings-kb.html

`xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled` is set in your kibana.yml

But there is a ton of other settings. The config file depends on the specific setting.

Comment: yeah i have tried this, there is no pre-existing setting related to `xpack` and if i add settings myself then kibana stops working.

Comment: that's another story then. what exactly do you mean by "stops working"? Do you have some error log?